# How To Check IP with Given IP Range on LINQ C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, asp.net-core

I've an SQL Query like

```
WHERE Network <= @ipaddress AND LastIp >= @ipaddress
```

and i need to convert it to LINQ Query. Network and LastIp columns are string. I'm receiving @ipaddress from input at application.

```
string.Compare(ip.Network,ipAddress) == -1
&& string.Compare(ip.LastIp,ipAddress) == 1
```

is it okey to use string.Compare or is there another and much safer way to do that?
So thankful for any help.

```
PS: Need to compare directly into LINQ Query with Repository Context. So i tried to use IpAddress function but it gave the LINQ Expression error.
```

Comment: "is it okey to use string.Compare" have you encountered an issue using it?

Comment: Hello fifauser, there is no 'greater than' or 'less then' comparison operator available with IPAddress, you should build a function by yourself. I think you could find some classes ready to use with an online search.

Comment: An IPv4 number can be converted into an unsigned 32-bit integer. These numbers can be compared and check if they fall into a specific range.

Comment: @ManuelFabbri thank you i will check out.

Comment: @gunr2171 actually no but i just wondered if there is any other option

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461742/how-to-convert-an-ipv4-address-into-a-integer-in-c/13350494#13350494

Comment: There are some methods in this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160776/how-would-you-compare-ip-address), Maybe you can refer to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can `convert IP to uint` using the following function:

```
  public uint IpAddressToUint(string ipAddress)
  {
      var address = IPAddress.Parse(ipAddress);
      byte[] bytes = address.GetAddressBytes();
      return BitConverter.ToUInt32(bytes, 0);
  }
```

and compare uints:

```
IpAddressToUint(ip.Network) <= IpAddressToUint(ipAddress) && 
IpAddressToUint(ip.LastIp) >= IpAddressToUint(ipAddress)
```

Comment: Works for IPv4 only, and is sensitive to endian-ness